# show that if $T$ is a tree containing at least one vertex of degree $2$ then $\overline T$ is not Eulerian.

Tags: graph-theory

show that if $T$ is a tree containing at least one vertex of degree $2$ then $\overline T$ is not Eulerian.

I know that every tree has at least 2 leaves, so they can't be Eulerian. So in $\overline T$, these 2 leaves will adjacent to eachother. But I'm now sure if they stay being odd vertices or not. Is there a way to link the degree of vertices of $T$ and its complement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A leaf of T has degree $1$, and there is a vertex with degree $2$. So, the complement of
 T has a vertex with degree $n-2$ and a vertex with degree $n-3$, so the complement of T cannot
 have vertices which degrees are all even.

Comment: the complement of $T$ has a vertex with degree $n−2$ and a vertex with degree $n−3$. This is a theorem or some proposition? I wonder if you have the name of this theorem?

Comment: Not a theorem ... If a vertex has degree $k$, it has degree $n-1-k$ in its complement.